# How can I break up $z = \frac{5}{9+3i}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Into its real and imaginary components?  Wolfram tells me it's equivalent to $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{6}$, but I don't know how to arrive there myself.

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: Try multiplying by $(9-3i)/(9-3i)$.

Comment: You might want to extract obvious factors to give $z = \cfrac 5 3 .\cfrac 1 {3+i} .\cfrac {3-i}{3-i}$

Comment: Going with Sean's hint, think of what happens when you multiply a complex number by its conjugate.

Comment: The general procedure is to multiply the numerator and denominator of the given complex fraction by the complex conjugate of the denomnator when that denominator is not real.

Answer (score 6):

$z = \frac{5}{9+3i} = \frac{5(9-3i)}{(9+3i)(9-3i)} = \frac{45-15i}{9^2 + 3^2} = \frac{45}{90} - \frac{15i}{90} = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{i}{6}$

Answer (score 1):

Here, we must use our knowledge of complex numbers and their conjugates as well as our knowledge of the difference of squares:

$z = \frac{5}{9+3i}$

$ = \frac{5(9-3i)}{(9+3i)(9-3i)}$

$ = \frac{45-15i}{9^2 - (i^2)(3^2)}$

$ = \frac{45-15i}{90}$

$ = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{6}i$